# Display multiple graphics with Seaborn

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, catplot, stripplot

I have a csv file that I open with Pandas. It looks like this:

```
"Patient","Visit","Feature1","Feature2","Feature3"
"P1",0,?,?,?
"P1",1,?,?,?
"P2",0,?,?,?
"P2",1,?,?,?
"P2",2,?,?,?
"P3",0,?,?,?
"P3",1,?,?,?
```

`?` being a numerical value.

I know how to display one feature at a time (because they have various ranges) and separated per patient:

```
seaborn.stripplot(y="Feature1", x="Patient", data=features)
```

I would like to display ALL the plots inside a single image, like a mapping. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seaborn usually prefers the ["long form"](http://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html#long-form-vs-wide-form-data) of the dataframe, which can be obtained via pandas' [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"Patient": ["P1", "P1", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P3", "P3"],
                   "Visit": [0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1],
                   "Feature1": np.random.normal(10, 2, 7),
                   "Feature2": np.random.normal(12, 2, 7),
                   "Feature3": np.random.normal(15, 2, 7)})
df_melted = df.melt(value_vars=["Feature1", "Feature2", "Feature3"], id_vars=["Patient", "Visit"],
                    var_name="Feature", value_name="Value")
sns.stripplot(data=df_melted, x="Patient", y="Value", hue="Feature", dodge=True)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: seaborn stripplot with long form df]

To get each feature in separate subplots, you can use `catplot` on the melted dataframe (use `sharey=True` if all features are in about the same range; use `col_wrap=3` to start a new row every 3 columns):

```py
sns.catplot(kind="strip", data=df_melted, x="Patient", y="Value", col="Feature", sharey=False)
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: catplot on melted dataframe]

Comment: Thanks, but it's a single graphic, I need to separate each feature in different graphics and then display them side by side

Comment: Yes, it is. Thank you very much, I'll try it and let you know.